# Needed to keep fixed time frame , even after chnages

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

Thanks for reading this,
After a lot of googling and searching, I was able to create a script that marks high and low candles with the highest volume

The problem currently I am facing is I wanted it to be on 15min time frame, currently, when I change my time frame from 15 to 1hr or any other, the script gets applied to that time frame, is there some way to keep the default time frame?

```
//@version=4
study("Volume High", shorttitle="VolHigh", overlay=true)

// This is a collab project with kisshore19 to mark the highest volume bar per day on the chart (specifically for lower timeframe charts, such as 5m)
i1 = input("", type = input.resolution)
var int dailyT = dayofweek
var float highestVolume = 0.0
var line hvMarkerHigh = na // line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=low, x2=bar_index, y2=high, xloc=xloc.bar_index, extend=extend.both, color=color.blue, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
var line hvMarkerLow = na
var int extendDistance = input(defval=10000000, title="Bar Extend Distance (MS)", type=input.integer) // extend distance in bars == bars * minutes * milliseconds
var color topLine = input(defval=color.black, title="Top Line", type=input.color)
var color botLine = input(defval=color.black, title="Bottom Line", type=input.color)

// once a new day starts, set hvMarker to na so we don't delete previous days' high volume marks
if dayofweek != dailyT
    // have moved to the next day
    highestVolume := 0
    hvMarkerHigh := na
    hvMarkerLow := na
    dailyT := dayofweek

if  hour(time) != 09 and minute(time) != 20 and hour(time) != 03 and minute(time) != 15 and volume > highestVolume
    highestVolume := volume
    line.delete(hvMarkerHigh)
    line.delete(hvMarkerLow)
    hvMarkerHigh := line.new(x1=time, y1=high, x2=time + extendDistance, y2=high, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=topLine, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
    hvMarkerLow := line.new(x1=time, y1=low, x2=time + extendDistance, y2=low, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=botLine, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
```

Pust suggestion to convert  to version 5 getting following error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Convert your current script into Version 5 Pine Script.

[Step 2: Upon the first line, add in this line: timeframe = "D". You may replace "D" with your own default timeframe. Done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBYt0.png)

Comment: I am getting the following error:  line 24: The 'timeframe' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).